# JavaFX Transition: Invert button color

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, transition

I want to change the color of a button to it's invert color and back as a transition.

I was able to use Timeline with ColorAdjust to do this with the brightness, but I didn't found a effect class to transition the color of a button with Timeline.

Hope someone out there is able to help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A inversion effect can be achieved by using a [`Blend`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/effect/Blend.html) effect with [`BlendMode.DIFFERENCE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/effect/BlendMode.html#DIFFERENCE) and a `topInput` that is black for no inversion and white for completely inverted colors. Example:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Blend blendEffect = new Blend(BlendMode.DIFFERENCE);
    ColorInput input = new ColorInput();
    blendEffect.setTopInput(input);
    Button btn = new Button("Inversion Animation");
    input.widthProperty().bind(btn.widthProperty());
    input.heightProperty().bind(btn.heightProperty());
    btn.setEffect(blendEffect);
    btn.setStyle("-fx-body-color: orange;");

    DoubleProperty brightness = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
    input.paintProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> Color.BLACK.interpolate(Color.WHITE, brightness.get()), brightness));

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(brightness, 0d)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), new KeyValue(brightness, 1d))
    );
    timeline.setOnFinished(evt -> timeline.setRate(-timeline.getRate()));

    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        timeline.play();
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```